# Angular Directive parsed attr two-way binding

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive

I am creating an angular Directive called evoEventMirror, whose purpose is attach a jquery event to an inserted element and apply a specified css style to the "root" element.
See example below:

```
<div id="#mydiv" evo-event-mirror target="#otherdiv" event="transitionEnd" action="hideMenu == true ? {'border':'1px solid blue'} : {'border':'1px solid red'}">
       <!--...-->
</div>
```

In this case, #otherdiv will bind transitionEnd event and apply the border style(action) to #mydiv when the event is fired.

Now, the problem is i can't create an isolated scope, so i can't obtain double binding variables.
I tried to use the attributes of the element as an input source, but i can't intercept any change if the variable "hidemenu" changes.

```
evoDirectives.directive('evoEventMirror', ['$parse',function ($parse) { 
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var test = $parse(attrs.action)(scope);
            scope.$watch(test, function (newValue) {
                console.log('update');
            });             

           //apply some style..
            target.bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend', function () {
                var css = angular.element(element).attr('style');
                if (css == null) css = style;
                else css += style;

                element.attr('style', css);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully resolved my issue.
The problem was the "hidemenu" variable itself: it was stored in a isolated scope, so i was referencing a "new" variable hidemenu which was every time false.

Using a normal watcher over the attrs, however, did the trick.

Thanks for answers, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i believe that the watch is not of much use here as `test` is not a scope variable.

What you can do is to create a watch function like this:

```
            var getter = $parse(attrs.action);
            scope.$watch(function() {
                             return getter(scope);
                         }, 
                        function (newValue) {
                                 console.log('update');
                        });
```

This watch function (first argument) now fire every time on digest cycle. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need isolate scope on directive, something like this (not tested):

```
.directive('evoEventMirror', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'action': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.action);            
        }
    }
});
```

A good guide you can read is [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)

Comment: I can't really create a scope variable, sadly. The purpose of my directive is to be attached to any element, so i can't be sure if the other element has got already an isolated scope.